# mysql query to filter by multiple coordinates boundaries

Tags: java, mysql, geolocation, mybatis, boundary

I have a database containing a list of cities with coordinates, and I am using mybatis with this query to find cities given a boundary.

```
SELECT * FROM cities 
WHERE lat > #{latMin} 
AND lat < #{latMax} 
AND lng > #{lngMin} 
AND lng < #{lngMax}
```

Now I have multiple boundaries and I call the query multiple times to have all the cities contained in all the boundaries, and things are getting slower.

To speed the things up, without changing my architecture, can I have a single query that takes in input a (maybe very long) list of boundaries? Maybe a stored procedure?

The contraints on this project are mybatis as persistence layer and mysql as db.

edit:
this is my current mybatis method.

```
List<CityDTO> getCityNearPoint(@Param("latMin") Double latMin, @Param("latMax") Double latMax, 
             @Param("lngMin") Double lngMin, @Param("lngMax") Double lngMax);
```

I don't know how to pass an array of objects that contains the boundaries and map them to multiple ORs. Something like:

```
List<CityDTO> getCityNearBoundaries(BoundaryDTO[] boundaries);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just combine multiple boundaries using OR. You can achive it using Dynamic SQL (s. foreach) or @SqlProvider annotated method, that will generate an appropriate SQL String. I would prefer to use Dynamic SQL.
In xml it will look like this:

```
<select id="selectCitiesByBoundaries" resultType="CityDTO">
  SELECT * FROM cities WHERE
  <foreach item="boundary" index="index" collection="#{boundaries}"
      open=" (" separator=") OR (" close=") ">
    lat > #{boundary.getLatMin()} AND
    lat < #{boundary.getLatMax()} AND
    lng > #{boundary.getLngMin()} AND
    lng < #{boundary.getLngMax()}
  </foreach>
</select>
```

Comment: I don't understand how I can pass an array of objects and map them to multiple ORs. I'll edit my question to clarify.